# A way in Rmarkdown to copy specific ranges in excel and paste them as images?

Tags: r, excel, image, ms-word, r-markdown

I have several formatted tables (and some graphs) in a single excel book, and I want to use Rmarkdown to grab those tables and graphs and add them to the knitted word document as images. I cannot simply copy the cell range with Readxl or other packages because all cells lose their formatting, and I need the tables in the document to look exactly the same as in the spreadsheet.

Alternatively, I am considering recreating the tables in R, but again the new tables will not have the formatting (though I imagine kable could allow me to recreate all the formatting). This is certainly not ideal, however, since I'm creating the tables twice, so hopefully the copy ability is doable somehow. I know Rmarkdown can use Python, Javascript, and many other languages, so maybe one of those languages is capable of this.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For formatted tables in rmarkdown, you might consider the not-yet-on-CRAN [`gt`](https://github.com/rstudio/gt) package, it provides a bit more formatting options. I don't know of an easy way to automate grabbing screenshots of portions of excel worksheets ... though it might be feasible to find a DDE method (out of my league).

Comment: Better to write a VBA script in the Excel file to export all charts as image (e.g., TIF) then use RMarkdown to import those. Search on this site for such VBA script.